# Vlookup AND check if cell contains other critera

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a Google Sheet that has the following tabs:

- `Shops` || This contains a few drop-down menus
- `!Data_ShopInventory` || This contains columns A-I and is effectively the 'database'
- `!Data_Shops` || This contains some randomly generated stuff based on the other tabs and then the Shops tab pulls from it

I have the following formula:

```
={"Items";SORTN(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, SEARCH(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I)), 5, 0, ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("1,",COUNTA(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, search(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I)))), ",", 0, 1)), 10000)), 1)}
```

This works as such: Based on the drop-down menu selected on the `Shops` tab (cell C3), it will then randomly pull 5 items from the `!Data_ShopInventory` (Col A) tab.

In the `!Data_ShopInventory` tab, I have a column (Town Size) that contains text as follows:

- Large
- Medium
- Medium,Large
- Small,Medium
- Small
- Small,Medium,Large

I need to make my vlookup that returns the random item also take this into account.
On the `Shops` tab, there is another drop-down menu (cell C4) that has the options of Small, Medium or Large.

So if I select 'Large', I want the vlookup to only return random items where C3 matches (like it currently does in the above formula) and where the corresponding cell in Col G contains the selection from the drop-down in C4.

Tried a bunch and I just can't figure it out... It's 1:30am and I am tired. Anyone able to help?

Here is a link to the sheet:
[Google Sheet Copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15S-gqR7bNKE998Pj8usbQDSllJQuEXUZ9BY0aYzs3dA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thought I had done that. My bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

delete G1:J1 and use in G1:

```
={"Standard Price", "Discounted Price", "Inflated Price", "Limited Stock"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(F2:F), IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F, 
 FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!A:H, REGEXMATCH('!Data_ShopInventory'!G:G, Shops!C4)), {3,4,5,8}, )), ))}
```

[image]

### update:

```
={"Items";SORTN(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, SEARCH(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I),REGEXMATCH('!Data_ShopInventory'!G2:G, Shops!C4)), 30, 0, ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("1,",COUNTA(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, search(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I),REGEXMATCH('!Data_ShopInventory'!G2:G, Shops!C4)))), ",", 0, 1)), 10000)), 1)}
```

Comment: That certainly works better than a bunch of vlookups, but it wasn't actually what I was asking for (thanks anyways!). I need the items in ColF on the !Data_Shops sheet to populate  based on the drop downs in the Shops sheet (cells C3 and C4). C3 lookup is already working, it can find stuff for the blacksmith, but I need it to also only find it where the C4 value matches against '!Data_ShopInventory'!G:G. So if we look at the item Plate, its only available in large shops. So I only want to randomly pull it if the C4 drop down is Large. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: I think I sussed it based on your answer though:
={"Items";SORTN(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, SEARCH(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I),REGEXMATCH('!Data_ShopInventory'!G2:G, Shops!C4)), 30, 0, ARRAYFORMULA(RANDBETWEEN(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT("1,",COUNTA(FILTER('!Data_ShopInventory'!$A$2:$A, search(Shops!$C$3, '!Data_ShopInventory'!$I$2:$I),REGEXMATCH('!Data_ShopInventory'!G2:G, Shops!C4)))), ",", 0, 1)), 10000)), 1)}

Answer (score 0):

> if I select 'Large', I want the vlookup to only return random items where C3 matches (like it currently does in the above formula) and where the corresponding cell in Col G contains the selection from the drop-down in C4.

So if I'm understanding correctly you want to return five random items from `!Data_ShopInventory` where `ShopType` matches `Shops!C3` and `TownSizeAvailable` matches `Shops!C4`. If that's what you are after, this formula will do the trick.

`={"Items";SortN(Query('!Data_ShopInventory'!A2:I,"select A where I='"&Shops!C3&"' and G like '%"&Shops!C4&"%'",0),5,,RandArray(SumProduct(('!Data_ShopInventory'!I2:I=Shops!C3)*RegexMatch('!Data_ShopInventory'!G2:G,Shops!C4))),0)}`